# timestamps in geographic location how to aggregate with machine learning pandas ipython notebook

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, jupyter-notebook

I have a huge file full of time series data the only column is time
 **the only column in the whole data set is the time column**

```
time
2017-02-01 00:11:55
2017-02-01 00:21:04
```

it is 100,000 rows long with 1 column, these are timestamps in a geographic location, I am trying to aggregate these timestamps based on 30 minute time intervals and then visualize them, is there anyone that can advise me on how to best do this with machine learning practices

if I do data_file.dtypes an object is returned

```
time    object
```

if I try resampling I get this error: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better to show your full data(not only time column), anyway I will show you the simple `resample` usage of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2017-02-01 00:11:55', '2017-12-31 12:30:00', freq='7Min'), columns=["TS"])
df['Value'] = 1

# Resample
print(df.set_index('TS').resample('30Min').sum())

                     Value
TS                        
2017-02-01 00:00:00      3
2017-02-01 00:30:00      4
2017-02-01 01:00:00      5
2017-02-01 01:30:00      4
2017-02-01 02:00:00      4
2017-02-01 02:30:00      5
...
```

Comment: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: thats the error i get when i try your method, ive already tried resampling it does not work

Comment: OK that's because your time column is just bunch of string not datetime unlike my sample data. Try to convert with `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` first.

Comment: I am trying to visualize this information and describe the resulting time series counts to show underlying patterns for forecasting, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: because when i try to plot using df['ltime'].plot(grid = True) it says, TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot